# Disable sparsebundle backups on Network-attached time machine (Lion)?

Tags: time-machine, backup

I am running OS X Lion/10.7.4 and have set up a network disk hosted on an Ubuntu server using [directions I found online](http://www.64bit.co.uk/index.php/archives/261). Time Machine recognizes the disk and backs up to it. However it backs up as sparsebundle "bands" files. I would like to be able to read the backed-up files from the Ubuntu server.

Is there any way to tell Time Machine to back up to regular files **instead of** using sparsebundle/bands files?

Comment: short answer, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a github project a short time ago, which handles the "read the backed-up files" part of this question:

https://github.com/torarnv/sparsebundlefs

That is good enough for my purposes.